# How to add a footer using AddFooterView with text from a String?

Tags: android, listview, header, footer

I've made an application with a `ListView`. I'm to trying to add a footer to my `ListView` (which scrolls along with the `ListView`), using `addFooterView`. In this footer I want to add a `TextView` with some text which is defined in my `Activity` as a `String` called `notification`.

I've tried several things but it wouldn't work.

My `ListActivity`, `RoosterWijzigingen.java`:

```
public class RoosterWijzigingen extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> roosterwijziginglist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();         

        String hour = "4";
        String info = "Af 123";
        String notification = "Het is 40min-rooster!";

        // Creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // Adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put("hour", hour);
        map.put("info", info);

        // Adding HashList to ArrayList
        roosterwijziginglist.add(map);}

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, roosterwijziginglist , R.layout.roosterwijzigingen, 
                            new String[] {"hour", "info"}, 
                            new int[] {R.id.hour, R.id.info});
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);           
   }
}
```

I get the information for the strings *hour*, *info* and *notification* from a JSON file, but I omited this to shorten the code.

`listplaceholder.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >            

        <ListView
                         android:id="@+id/android:list"
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

        <TextView
                         android:id="@id/android:empty"
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:text="No data" />
```

`roosterwijzigingen.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >                      

        <TextView  
                         android:id="@+id/hour"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                         android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <TextView  
                         android:id="@+id/info"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                         android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put your `String` in a `TextView` before adding it to your list, and it will look something like that :

```
String footerText = "Footer text";
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText(footerText);

getListView().addFooterView(textView);
```

Remember that 99% of the time when you want to display something on the screen, it has to be a [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

Comment: I've tried that, but my problem lies in the last line. I don't know how I have to call my ListView. That's where it goes wrong.
I'm sorry, I'll edit that in my question.

Comment: @user1946633 Use: `getListView().addFooterView(textView);` _before_ calling `setListAdapter()`.

Comment: I tried to put the following code in my Activity before calling setListAdapter():
    String footerText = "Footer text";
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText(footerText);
    getListView().addFooterView(textView); 

My app doesn't chrash anymore, but there is still no footer, it just looks the same as before.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try placing this after the setContentView. Maybe the text color is the same as your background and you don't see it. Try setting a different text color like this : `textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);`